# Perform insert with timestamp that increments

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a script inserting a few hundred thousand records into a table. One of the columns is a `DATETIME2(7)`, and I'm inserting `SYSUTCDATETIME()` into it. The problem is that every single record has the same exact time stamp. I'm trying to avoid doing a cursor or while loop, and just perform a nice fast insert into/select from kind of statement.

Is there a way to have the time increment, even it it's by nano seconds, in a straight insert?
e.g.

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Users]
     ( [FirstName]
     , [LastName]
     , [CreatedDate] )
SELECT  [DI].[FirstName] AS [FirstName]
      , [DI].[LastName]  AS [LastName]
      , SYSUTCDATETIME() AS [CreatedDate]
FROM    [dbo].[DataImport] AS [DI];
```

Comment: That absolutely did the trick, and without loops or row counters, or anything. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

These functions are sometimes referred to as *runtime constants*.  Each reference to the function in the query is evaluated once at runtime, but each row gets the same value fro the entire query execution.  SQL Server considers this a *feature* not a *bug*.

What can you do?  Well the first thing is to simply not rely on a timestamp for this differentiation.  Use an `identity` column to uniquely identify each row.  Then, this won't be an issue.

If, for some reason, you do have to use the date/time column, then you can make up your own constant.  For instance:

```
dateadd(microsecond, row_number() over (order by (select null)), SYSUTCDATETIME()
```

The timing isn't accurate.  But we are talking microseconds here (and you could use nanoseconds).

This does make key assumptions:

- You don't have concurrent inserts where the times can be overlapping.
- You are not running inserts so close in time that you might get overlaps.

Did I mention that you should be using an `identity` column instead?

Comment: The tables already have an identity column. What I need is a mass insert into the table, but with incremented timestamps on the rows. @ItalianStallion4215 had it exactly right.