# Create a table using T-SQL that uses some sort of timestamp as ID column

Tags: sql-server, performance, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to create a table that uses some sort of timestamp as the ID column with PK.
The goal is to create a table that can be sorted using the ID column which can be used to order the table using a numbering format searching according to the date and time the data was inserted. I know I can set the ID column using identity but I would like the column to be more useful.
I'm hoping there is an efficient way of doing this which provides a performance gain.
E.G. I know in excel you can put a date/time into a cell and it displays as a number depending on the format used.

Hope this is clear, I'm finding it hard to explain. Thanks,

Comment: Did you see this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66575082/perform-insert-with-timestamp-that-increments

Comment: And if you are seriously using SQL Server 2008 its time to upgrade.

Comment: Thanks Dale, I've checked out the link you provided and will see if this can help me. In regards to 2008R2, I totally agree and have upgraded a majority of the instances. The ones left are the painful ones where work is still being done to the databases so they can be upgraded.